# Ansible loop over registered results

Tags: ansible

I am looping over some python command and register its results in a variable called *scriptstatus*. An example output of scriptstatus is:

```
{
"scriptstatus": {
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "changed": true,
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "stderr_lines": [
                "WARNING:root:No device with given manufacturer and type found! Hint: Do you used HEX-numbers?"
            ],
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "end": "2018-08-28 12:02:26.992264",
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "stdout": "",
            "cmd": [
                "python3",
                "/home/pi/set_local_parameter.py",
                "--api",
                "openhab",
                "--parameter_num",
                "parameter_nums",
                "--parameter_val",
                "parameter_vals",
                "--word_size",
                "word_sizes",
                "--man_id",
                "010F",
                "--references",
                "0801:1001",
                "0801:2001",
                "0801:3001",
                "0801:4001",
                "8800:3001"
            ],
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2018-08-28 12:02:26.252247",
            "failed": false,
            "delta": "0:00:00.740017",
            "item": [
                "parameter_nums",
                "parameter_vals",
                "word_sizes"
            ],
            "changed": true,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "_uses_shell": false,
                    "_raw_params": "python3 /home/pi/set_local_parameter.py --api openhab --parameter_num parameter_nums --parameter_val parameter_vals --word_size word_sizes --man_id 010F --references 0801:1001 0801:2001 0801:3001 0801:4001 8800:3001",
                    "removes": null,
                    "argv": null,
                    "warn": true,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "stdin": null
                }
            },
            "stdout_lines": [],
            "stderr": "WARNING:root:No device with given manufacturer and type found! Hint: Do you used HEX-numbers?",
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_label": [
                "parameter_nums",
                "parameter_vals",
                "word_sizes"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"_ansible_verbose_always": true,
"_ansible_no_log": false,
"changed": false
}
```

In case of this example, there is only one result and I directly am able to access variables like *scriptstatus.results.0.changed*.

But I need to loop the results. What I tried to do is:

```
- name: Show possible warnings
  debug:
     var: "{{ item.changed }}"
  loop: "{{ scriptstatus.results }}"
```

But the output of this is:

```
{
"changed": false,
"_ansible_no_log": false,
"_ansible_item_result": true,
"item": {
    "_ansible_parsed": true,
    "stderr_lines": [
        "WARNING:root:No device with given manufacturer and type found! Hint: Do you used HEX-numbers?"
    ],
    "_ansible_item_result": true,
    "end": "2018-08-28 12:02:26.992264",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "stdout": "",
    "cmd": [
        "python3",
        "/home/pi/set_local_parameter.py",
        "--api",
        "openhab",
        "--parameter_num",
        "parameter_nums",
        "--parameter_val",
        "parameter_vals",
        "--word_size",
        "word_sizes",
        "--man_id",
        "010F",
        "--references",
        "0801:1001",
        "0801:2001",
        "0801:3001",
        "0801:4001",
        "8800:3001"
    ],
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2018-08-28 12:02:26.252247",
    "failed": false,
    "delta": "0:00:00.740017",
    "item": [
        "parameter_nums",
        "parameter_vals",
        "word_sizes"
    ],
    "changed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "_raw_params": "python3 /home/pi/set_local_parameter.py --api openhab --parameter_num parameter_nums --parameter_val parameter_vals --word_size word_sizes --man_id 010F --references 0801:1001 0801:2001 0801:3001 0801:4001 8800:3001",
            "removes": null,
            "argv": null,
            "warn": true,
            "chdir": null,
            "stdin": null
        }
    },
    "stdout_lines": [],
    "stderr": "WARNING:root:No device with given manufacturer and type found! Hint: Do you used HEX-numbers?",
    "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
    "_ansible_item_label": [
        "parameter_nums",
        "parameter_vals",
        "word_sizes"
    ]
},
"true": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!",
"_ansible_verbose_always": true,
"_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
"_ansible_item_label": {
    "_ansible_parsed": true,
    "stderr_lines": [
        "WARNING:root:No device with given manufacturer and type found! Hint: Do you used HEX-numbers?"
    ],
    "_ansible_item_result": true,
    "end": "2018-08-28 12:02:26.992264",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "stdout": "",
    "failed": false,
    "cmd": [
        "python3",
        "/home/pi/set_local_parameter.py",
        "--api",
        "openhab",
        "--parameter_num",
        "parameter_nums",
        "--parameter_val",
        "parameter_vals",
        "--word_size",
        "word_sizes",
        "--man_id",
        "010F",
        "--references",
        "0801:1001",
        "0801:2001",
        "0801:3001",
        "0801:4001",
        "8800:3001"
    ],
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2018-08-28 12:02:26.252247",
    "delta": "0:00:00.740017",
    "item": [
        "parameter_nums",
        "parameter_vals",
        "word_sizes"
    ],
    "changed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "warn": true,
            "executable": null,
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "_raw_params": "python3 /home/pi/set_local_parameter.py --api openhab --parameter_num parameter_nums --parameter_val parameter_vals --word_size word_sizes --man_id 010F --references 0801:1001 0801:2001 0801:3001 0801:4001 8800:3001",
            "removes": null,
            "argv": null,
            "creates": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "stdin": null
        }
    },
    "stdout_lines": [],
    "stderr": "WARNING:root:No device with given manufacturer and type found! Hint: Do you used HEX-numbers?",
    "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
    "_ansible_item_label": [
        "parameter_nums",
        "parameter_vals",
        "word_sizes"
    ]
}
}
```

First I was wondering, why the whole item is printed. But then I recognized the line

```
"true": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

When using

```
- name: Show possible warnings
      debug:
         mgs: "{{ item.changed }}"
      loop: "{{ scriptstatus.results }}"
```

the output has only small changes, e.g. *VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!* is missing. E.g. the output is:

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "_ansible_item_result": true,
    "item": {
        "_ansible_parsed": true,
        "stderr_lines": [
            "WARNING:root:No device with given manufacturer and type found! Hint: Do you used HEX-numbers?"
        ],
        "_ansible_item_result": true,
        "end": "2018-08-29 08:17:16.423869",
        "_ansible_no_log": false,
        "stdout": "",
        "cmd": [
            "python3",
            "/home/pi/set_local_parameter.py",
            "--api",
            "openhab",
            "--parameter_num",
            "80",
            "--parameter_val",
            "0",
            "--word_size",
            "1",
            "--man_id",
            "010F",
            "--references",
            "0801:1001",
            "0801:2001",
            "0801:3001",
            "0801:4001",
            "8800:3001"
        ],
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2018-08-29 08:17:15.647229",
        "failed": false,
        "delta": "0:00:00.776640",
        "item": [
            "80",
            "0",
            "1"
        ],
        "changed": true,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "_uses_shell": false,
                "_raw_params": "python3 /home/pi/set_local_parameter.py --api openhab --parameter_num 80 --parameter_val 0 --word_size 1 --man_id 010F --references 0801:1001 0801:2001 0801:3001 0801:4001 8800:3001",
                "removes": null,
                "argv": null,
                "warn": true,
                "chdir": null,
                "stdin": null
            }
        },
        "stdout_lines": [],
        "stderr": "WARNING:root:No device with given manufacturer and type found! Hint: Do you used HEX-numbers?",
        "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
        "_ansible_item_label": [
            "80",
            "0",
            "1"
        ]
    },
    "msg": true,
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
    "_ansible_item_label": {
        "_ansible_parsed": true,
        "stderr_lines": [
            "WARNING:root:No device with given manufacturer and type found! Hint: Do you used HEX-numbers?"
        ],
        "_ansible_item_result": true,
        "end": "2018-08-29 08:17:16.423869",
        "_ansible_no_log": false,
        "stdout": "",
        "failed": false,
        "cmd": [
            "python3",
            "/home/pi/set_local_parameter.py",
            "--api",
            "openhab",
            "--parameter_num",
            "80",
            "--parameter_val",
            "0",
            "--word_size",
            "1",
            "--man_id",
            "010F",
            "--references",
            "0801:1001",
            "0801:2001",
            "0801:3001",
            "0801:4001",
            "8800:3001"
        ],
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2018-08-29 08:17:15.647229",
        "delta": "0:00:00.776640",
        "item": [
            "80",
            "0",
            "1"
        ],
        "changed": true,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "warn": true,
                "executable": null,
                "_uses_shell": false,
                "_raw_params": "python3 /home/pi/set_local_parameter.py --api openhab --parameter_num 80 --parameter_val 0 --word_size 1 --man_id 010F --references 0801:1001 0801:2001 0801:3001 0801:4001 8800:3001",
                "removes": null,
                "argv": null,
                "creates": null,
                "chdir": null,
                "stdin": null
            }
        },
        "stdout_lines": [],
        "stderr": "WARNING:root:No device with given manufacturer and type found! Hint: Do you used HEX-numbers?",
        "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
        "_ansible_item_label": [
            "80",
            "0",
            "1"
        ]
    }
}
```

**What I instead want to achieve is, that only the output of the variable *changed* is printed for each result item. Example: **

```
{
    "msg": {
        "true"
    }
}
```

I do not understand the error/problem. For me my case looks exactly like the one that is described in the ansible docs at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop

I also looked into some similar stackoverflow posts which also had problems with results, but none of it was able to solve my problem.

EDIT: I am running Ansible 2.6.1

Comment: The code you posted is not the one you run. You made a typo and wrote `var` instead of `msg` in your real code.

Comment: Oh, you were right, sorry! I mixed up some code and results, as I tried to find a solution to my problem in various ways. If I use *msg* instead of *var*, the output is more or less similar to the above output. The only difference is that the "true": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" line is missing.

Comment: So what's the problem now?

Comment: I edited my question to be more precise. I only want the value of the variable *changed* to be printed.

Comment: Your marking as duplicate might be correct, as in your referenced question, they explain that some modules including the debug module have special output behaviour when used with loops. But the better answer to solving this issue with code that is readable was given in https://serverfault.com/questions/757461/ansible-with-items-dont-print-whole-item where they used the loop_control and label. Anyway, thanks for pointing to the first question which I did not see before and which led me to the other question!